# Обработчик проваленного теста

Tags: c++, юнит-тесты

Производится юнит-тестирование usb-устройства (CDC). Тест открывает устройство, формирует запрос, отправляет его устройству, проверяет ответ, закрывает устройство. В случае, если тест провален, закрытие устройства не выполнится, и, следовательно, все последующие тесты также будут провалены, так как не смогут открыть устройство. В связи с этим вопрос: есть ли способ установить обработчик (handler, hook) проваленного теста, который бы выполнял освобождение ресурсов, запрошенных тестирующей функцией?

Тесты создаются в Visual Studio, тип проекта c++ unit test.

Comment: в большинстве xUnit фреймворков есть методы setUp(), tearDown() как раз для этих целей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваши ответы подсказали мне, в какой области искать верный ответ. В Visual Studio в Native Unit test методы до и после тестирования объявляются следующим образом:

```
TEST_METHOD_INITIALIZE(methodName) 
{
    // method initialization code
}

TEST_METHOD_CLEANUP(methodName) 
{
    // test method cleanup  code
}
```

Внутри этих методов можно генерировать исключения и вызывать функции из статического класса Assert.

Больше информации здесь: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/hh694604.aspx)

Comment: Отметьте потом ваш ответ как правильный.

Answer (score 3):

В тестовых фреймворках всегда есть возможность указать код, который будет выполнять перед каждым тестом и после каждого теста. Этот код выполняется всегда, вне зависимости от результата теста. Соответственно в вашем сценарии можно сделать так:

1. Код перед тестом открывает устройство.
2. Выполняется тест.
3. Код после теста закрывает устройство.

В MSTest для этого используются атрибуты [`TestInitialize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testinitializeattribute.aspx) и [`TestCleanup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcleanupattribute.aspx).

P.S. Только это у вас не юнит-тестирование, а интеграционное тестирование. В юнит-тестировании не используются сторонние зависимости.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но у меня используется C++, а не C#.

Comment: @maestro да. Я подумал, что для С++ тоже MSTest используется. Вижу ваш ответ, в общем суть та же, только способ немного отличается.